# AngularJS A controller with this name is not registered

Tags: angularjs

Soy nuevo en AngularJS y no sé como solucionar el siguiente error:
*Error: $controller:ctrlreg
A controller with this name is not registered.*
Estoy utilizado el módulo ui-router para mi aplicación, aunque sin él sigo teniendo el mismo error, dejo el código de los archivos implicados:

> main.php

```
<?php ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>INICIO</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div><BIENVENIDOS A MI APP</div>
    <a ui-sref="login">ENTRAR</a>
    <div ui-view></div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../back-end/scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../back-end/scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> app.js

```
angular.module('myApp',[
    'ui.router'
])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
    .state('login',{
        url:'/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.php',
        controller:'loginController',
        });
}])
```

> loginController.js

```
  angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('loginController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.algo = "Algo";  
  }]);
```

Un saludo, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta hacerlo de esta manera.

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.algo = "Algo";  
  }]);
```

adicional tienes que agregar loginController.js en el index en tu caso seria el main.php pero despues del app.js

algo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../back-end/scripts/loginController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Me resultó muy útil tu repuestas, gracias!